# Read newly-delivered files by Spark whenever files land into s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I want to read files using Spark whenever files land into s3.

I do not want to use lambda function, instead I am trying to find some other ways to read files from AWS s3 whenever newer files land into s3 bucket.

Does AWS provides any such event notification to Spark?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is only an AWS thing.

As per the `Databricks` suggested approach these days, which is to try and avoid pure batch, you could set up Spark Structured Streaming to process incoming files as a Trigger of files in a watched directory (by Spark) as opposed to KAFKA events.

You then get a sort of "trickle feed" processing - of files.

You can set it up Spark Structured Streaming to process a long interval, 1 or N files at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an always-running Spark streaming job that uses a file stream as its input (you usually supply a path with wildcards, like `s3://bucket/path/*.json`). Your job will monitor that path and whenever a new file appears there, it will process it.

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#file-streams